# Write text to file using stream writer

Tags: c#, streamwriter, system.io.file

I am having some trouble writing a string `MentionsInText` to a file using the `Systems.IO.StreamWriter` according to the file it is edited when the code is run however, no text is present in the file. I am not sure why this is not working.
My code is as follows;

```
 var MIS = string.Join(" ", MentionsList.ToArray());
 string Mentionsintext = MIS.ToString();

 StreamWriter MentionFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Mentions.txt");

 MentionFile.WriteLine(Mentionsintext + Environment.NewLine);
```

Am I doing something wrong when using `StreamWriter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dispose of the StreamWriter after writing to it.

eg:

```
 var MIS = string.Join(" ", MentionsList.ToArray());
 string Mentionsintext = MIS.ToString();

 using (StreamWriter MentionFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Mentions.txt")) {

      MentionFile.WriteLine(Mentionsintext + Environment.NewLine);

 }
```

For more examples: see https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter

Comment: Thank you! from this would i be correct in saying that the same could be said for the use of `streamreader`?

Comment: @bdg You should always dispose of streams when you are finished with them. The easiest way of doing this is wrapping them in a `using(...)` statement as Nsevens suggested. In the example above, disposing of the stream causes `Flush()` to be called. In addition to doing this, it releases any unmanaged resources that the stream is using, thus preventing memory leaks.